# Why is CAShapeLayer too big despite setting contentsScale?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I have a CAShapeLayer that I'm using to draw tiny dots in a bar chart. The problem is that they are all too big on the retina displays. I have set the contentsScale and checked that it is getting set. Still I see no difference with it or without it!

```
CAShapeLayer *lineShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
lineShapeLayer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]; 
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
lineShapeLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
lineShapeLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.backgroundLayer.bounds.size.width, 1.5);

lineShapeLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
lineShapeLayer.position = CGPointMake(0, rint((self.verticalPartitionHeight)*i));
lineShapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], nil];
lineShapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
lineShapeLayer.lineWidth = 1;
NSLog(@"contentsScale: %f", lineShapeLayer.contentsScale);

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, .5);       
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, lineShapeLayer.frame.size.width, .5);
[lineShapeLayer setPath:path];

[self.backgroundLayer addSublayer:lineShapeLayer];
```

Here is the view if I make it with PNGs:
[image: PNGs showing 1px dots]

Here is the view with the CAShapeLayer code (set to line width .5 even.):
[image: CAShapeLayer showing 4px dots :(]

Comment: The content scale doesn't affect the size of the shape, only the resolution (i.e. it looks sharp on a retina display but stays the same size)

Comment: I'm assuming that `P(0,0)` is a convenience method or `CGPointMake(0,0)`. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with you code **unless its somewhere else**. I ran the code above inside a loop (I'm assuming `i` is the index) with `self.verticalPartitionHeight = 30.0`.

The two images below are the result in both normal resolution and retina resolution. I've scaled up the normal image to make them the same size. The dots are, as you can see, the same size (in points, not pixels) on both resolutions.

[image: Normal resolution, scaled up two times]

[image: Retina resolution]

#### Edit:

You mention that the Stocks app does this in Landscape but if you zoom in on a screenshot of it you will actually see that it actually uses points (since every dot is 2x2 pixels). You can see this in the screenshot below (from a retina screenshot) where I zoomed in a lot on the dots and selected one pixel of one dot.

This *is* the expected behavior.

[image: Stocks.app dots]

#### Edit 2:

One more zoomed up look at your dots. They are actually **the exact same size** as the dots in Apples Stocks app. You can see it in the image below where I have selected *one* pixel.

[image]

Comment: Thank u. But that's my problem. I want the dots smaller on retina.

Comment: _Why_ would you want that? Nothing else on the phone behaves that way. **IF** you really think its a good idea, just divide the line width by the scale factor and divide the lineDashPattern numbers with the same scale factor. That will make the dots smaller but it _won't_ make it a good idea.

Comment: The designer's comps call for 1px dots. I'm able to get them with PNGs but I really need to draw them.

Comment: And when I divide them, it's no smaller.

Comment: This is the same as Apple's stock app if you flip it to landscape.

Comment: Are you sure that you designer is actually away of the difference between points and pixels? I often see designers talking about measurements in pixels on the retina display when I know they really mean points. The relative size of your dots compared to other elements like text will be different in your design. You should show the designer how it looks and ask them if it's what they really meant.

Comment: Oh yes, he is aware. What's frustrating is that I can achieve the single pixel dot with a PNG.

Comment: And take a look at the stocks. That's still smaller than my dots! :) I feel like I'm going insane. haha.

Comment: @WillLarche No. the dots are exactly the same size!

Comment: Ach. progress. I just wasn't seeing. If I set it the scale to 2 and the line width to .5 they are the right width but still too tall.

Answer (score 0):

@David Ronnqvist was right! The contentsScale was working. I just had to make the line width even smaller and then put the whole thing on the .25 (which is .5/2)!

```
    CAShapeLayer *lineShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    lineShapeLayer.contentsScale=[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]; 
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    lineShapeLayer.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    lineShapeLayer.bounds=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.backgroundLayer.bounds.size.width, 0.5);

    lineShapeLayer.anchorPoint=P(0,0);
    lineShapeLayer.position=P(0,rint((self.verticalPartitionHeight)*i));
    lineShapeLayer.lineDashPattern=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], nil];
    lineShapeLayer.strokeColor=[UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    lineShapeLayer.lineWidth=0.5;
    lineShapeLayer.shadowColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    lineShapeLayer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(0, 0.5);
    lineShapeLayer.shadowOpacity=1.0;
    lineShapeLayer.shadowRadius=0;


    NSLog(@"lineShapeLayer.frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(lineShapeLayer.frame));
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0.25);       
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, lineShapeLayer.frame.size.width, 0.25);
    [lineShapeLayer setPath:path];
```

Of course I'll make this not hardcoded for scale but divisible by the scale.

[image: Looks perfect]

Answer (score 0):

Best way to scale `CAShapeLayer` is the following:

```
CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];   
[pathLayer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)];
```